# Kafka - Who writes to the __consumer_offsets topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am a bit confused about who writes to the __consumer_offset topic.

In Kafka definitive guide ch.4 p.75 is quite generic about this detail

> How does a consumer commit an offset? It produces a message to Kafka, to a special __consumer_offsets topic, with the committed offset for each partition.

In an other [website](https://www.sderosiaux.com/articles/2017/08/07/looking-at-kafka-s-consumers-offsets/) I have been reading this about the Group Coordinator being an offset manager as well. I went back to the confluent documentation and I have found [this article](https://www.confluent.io/blog/apache-kafka-data-access-semantics-consumers-and-membership/?_ga=2.160476664.418069568.1624261807-257159534.1622121890&_gac=1.157937224.1623849190.CjwKCAjwwqaGBhBKEiwAMk-FtOp0nGiDHQ4qhPnkLdaYoZbZeadvo50L_Q1p7oEuiZAsQ7Tz2aBf4BoCsjQQAvD_BwE):

> Remember the __consumer_offsets topic? Each consumer group stores the state of all its consumers inside a single partition of that topic. The group coordinator broker is the leader for that consumer group’s partition. This way, every broker can be a group coordinator. With enough groups, every broker will work as a coordinator for a different subset of consumer groups.

But I could not found a reference about who is writing the updates about commit offset to the __consumer_offset internal topic. Is it the consumer? Is it the group coordinator? Is it something else internal?

Comment: _could not find a reference_ ... Try looking in the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group coordinator writes to `__consumer_offsets` topic.
From [here](https://www.conduktor.io/kafka/kafka-consumer-groups-and-consumer-offsets/)

> Most client libraries automatically commit offsets to Kafka for you on
> a periodic basis, and the responsible Kafka broker will ensure writing
> to the __consumer_offsets topic (therefore consumers do not write to
> that topic directly).